# Error " C compiler works... no" when run build_android.sh

Tags: android, c++, c, linux, android-ndk

I follow to https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg to build ffmpeg for android, but when run ./build_android.sh be error

```
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for arm-linux-gcc... /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

please help me in this step.
I use Ubuntu 13.04 64bit OS

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by vo-amrwbenc configure 0.1.2, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/../ffmpeg-build/armeabi --host=arm-linux --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-shared --enable-static --with-pic

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = ubuntu
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.8.0-19-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /home/toai/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
PATH: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2186: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2254: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2265: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2315: result: yes
configure:2364: checking for arm-linux-strip
configure:2391: result: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip
configure:2456: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2495: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2508: checking for gawk
configure:2538: result: no
configure:2508: checking for mawk
configure:2524: found /usr/bin/mawk
configure:2535: result: mawk
configure:2546: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2568: result: yes
configure:2643: checking how to create a ustar tar archive
configure:2656: tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.26
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
configure:2659: $? = 0
configure:2699: tardir=conftest.dir && eval tar --format=ustar -chf - "$tardir" >conftest.tar
configure:2702: $? = 0
configure:2706: tar -xf - <conftest.tar
configure:2709: $? = 0
configure:2722: result: gnutar
configure:2740: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2757: result: yes
configure:2771: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:2780: result: no
configure:2799: checking build system type
configure:2813: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2833: checking host system type
configure:2846: result: arm-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2929: checking for style of include used by make
configure:2957: result: GNU
configure:2988: checking for arm-linux-gcc
configure:3015: result: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/
configure:3284: checking for C compiler version
configure:3293: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ --version >&5
./configure: line 3295: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3304: $? = 127
configure:3293: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ -v >&5
./configure: line 3295: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3304: $? = 127
configure:3293: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ -V >&5
./configure: line 3295: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3304: $? = 127
configure:3293: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3295: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3304: $? = 127
configure:3324: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3346: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ -marm -march=armv5 -marm -march=armv5 -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3348: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:3350: $? = 127
configure:3388: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "vo-amrwbenc"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "vo-amrwbenc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1.2"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "vo-amrwbenc 0.1.2"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "vo-amrwbenc"
| #define VERSION "0.1.2"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3393: error: in `/home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc':
configure:3395: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCASFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_set=
ac_cv_env_CCAS_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/'
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-marm -march=armv5'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value='-marm -march=armv5'
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value='-Wl,-rpath-link=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog'
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=arm-linux
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=arm-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=mawk
ac_cv_prog_CC='/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/'
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes
am_cv_prog_tar_ustar=gnutar

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/missing --run aclocal-1.11'
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE='#'
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='0'
AM_V='$(V)'
AR='/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar'
ARMV5E_FALSE=''
ARMV5E_TRUE='#'
ARMV7NEON_FALSE=''
ARMV7NEON_TRUE='#'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/missing --run automake-1.11'
AWK='mawk'
CC='/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/'
CCAS=''
CCASDEPMODE=''
CCASFLAGS=''
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS='-marm -march=armv5'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS='-marm -march=armv5'
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS=''
DEPDIR='.deps'
DLLTOOL=''
DSYMUTIL=''
DUMPBIN=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXAMPLE_FALSE=''
EXAMPLE_TRUE='#'
EXEEXT=''
FGREP=''
GREP=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LD=''
LDFLAGS='-Wl,-rpath-link=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog'
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LIBTOOL_DEPS=''
LIPO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
MAINTAINER_MODE_FALSE=''
MAINTAINER_MODE_TRUE='#'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/missing --run makeinfo'
MANIFEST_TOOL=''
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
NM='/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm'
NMEDIT=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OTOOL64=''
OTOOL=''
PACKAGE='vo-amrwbenc'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/'
PACKAGE_NAME='vo-amrwbenc'
PACKAGE_STRING='vo-amrwbenc 0.1.2'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='vo-amrwbenc'
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.1.2'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
RANLIB='/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib'
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip'
VERSION='0.1.2'
VO_AMRWBENC_VERSION=''
ac_ct_AR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_DUMPBIN=''
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCCAS_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__include='include'
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='tar --format=ustar -chf - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='tar -xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_vendor='unknown'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='arm-unknown-linux-gnu'
host_alias='arm-linux'
host_cpu='arm'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='unknown'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='/bin/mkdir -p'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc/../ffmpeg-build/armeabi'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "vo-amrwbenc"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "vo-amrwbenc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1.2"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "vo-amrwbenc 0.1.2"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/"
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define PACKAGE "vo-amrwbenc"
#define VERSION "0.1.2"

configure: exit 77
```

Comment: Can you post your config.log also?

Comment: is `libffmpeg.so` file created please look at `FFmpegLibrary/jni/ffmpeg-build/{armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86}/libffmpeg.so`

Comment: I posted config.log, please help me fix it

Answer (score 1):

You must look into the config.log file. Search for lines containing `error:`. These lines show where the configure process detected problems or missing components.

Then look above the error for a command line like

```
gcc -D_ISOC99_SOURCE -std=c99 -E -o /tmp/ffconf.blSwtBlI.o /tmp/ffconf.b17GLMRQ.c
```

You can also look toward the end of config.log, seeing if you can spot the problem there.

In your case it might well be, the compiler itself is missing some important library or configuration. You can investigate this further by creating a simple hello world program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and compile this on the command line with

```
/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc hello.c
```

and see what the compiler outputs.

*Update:*

In your config.log, you have these lines

> configure:3393: error: in `/home/toai/AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/vo-amrwbenc':
>   configure:3395: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Now when you go up a few lines, you see

> configure:3324: checking whether the C compiler works
>   configure:3346: /home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/ -marm -march=armv5 -marm -march=armv5 -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/platforms/android-5/arch-arm//usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog conftest.c  >&5
>   ./configure: line 3348: **/home/toai/Downloads/android-ndk-r9/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: No such file or directory**
>   configure:3350: $? = 127
>   configure:3388: result: no

This means it cannot find or execute the compiler. Maybe, you haven't installed it properly or it is located somewhere else. On my system, I can run gcc on the command line

> /path/to/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -v

and I get

> Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=/usr/local/opt/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   ...
>   Thread model: posix
>   gcc version 4.6 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC)

Comment: Exactly my case, upvoted! But I can't understand why configure tries to use arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3 toolchain which is missing in my NDK r9d. It has 4.6, 4.9 toolchains instead, and others, but there is no 4.4.3 one...

Comment: answering myself: paths to toolchains are specified in file **AndroidFFmpeg/FFmpegLibrary/jni/build_android.sh**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while compiling for x86 with android-ndk-r8b. It turns out that the file names in `android-ndk-{version}/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin` are not consistently named across different NDK versions. The order of 'android' and 'linux' seems to be switching.

The configure script cannot find the compiler because of this. It is pointing to `i686-android-linux-gcc` whereas the folder only contains a file named `i686-linux-android-gcc`.

You can fix the problem by making symlinks in the `android-ndk-{version}/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin` folder with the 'correct' names.

edit: the same goes for folder name `android-ndk-{version}/toolchains/x86-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android`

Comment: How to make symlinks in ubuntu 12+