# C compiler error: build ffmpeg for android

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, ffmpeg, cross-compiling

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
type OS 32 bit

I have clone git from

https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java

and wants to compile

but in some lines I am getting below error

```
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... ../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-3/arch-arm
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/home/amit/android-ffmpeg-java/external/android-ffmpeg/sox':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Config.log showing me following detail

```
    # ./configure --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --cross-prefix=../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-3/arch-arm --extra-cflags='-I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags=-L../x264 --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoders --enable-encoders --enable-muxers --enable-demuxers --enable-parsers --enable-protocols --enable-filters --enable-avresample --enable-libfreetype --disable-indevs --enable-indev=lavfi --disable-outdevs --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --enable-muxer=md5
ACODEC_TESTS='ac3_fixed_test




pcm_s24daud_decoder='yes'
pcm_s24daud_encoder='yes'
pcm_s24le_decoder='yes'
pcm_s24le_demuxer='yes'
pcm_s24le_encoder='yes'
pcm_s24le_muxer='yes'
pcm_s24le_test='yes'
pcm_s32be_decoder='yes'
pcm_s32be_demuxer='yes'
pcm_s32be_encoder='yes'
pcm_s32be_muxer='yes'
pcm_s32be_test='yes'
pcm_s32le_decoder='yes'
pcm_s32le_demuxer='yes'
pcm_s32le_encoder='yes'
pcm_s32le_muxer='yes'
pcm_s32le_test='yes'
pcm_s8_decoder='yes'
pcm_s8_demuxer='yes'
pcm_s8_encoder='yes'
pcm_s8_muxer='yes'
pcm_s8_planar_decoder='yes'
pcm_s8_test='yes'
pcm_test_deps='pcm_alaw_decoder pcm_alaw_encoder
pcm_f32be_decoder pcm_f32be_encoder
pcm_f32le_decoder pcm_f32le_encoder
pcm_f64be_decoder pcm_f64be_encoder
pcm_f64le_decoder pcm_f64le_encoder
pcm_mulaw_decoder pcm_mulaw_encoder
pcm_s8_decoder pcm_s8_encoder
pcm_s16be_decoder pcm_s16be_encoder
pcm_s16le_decoder pcm_s16le_encoder
pcm_s24be_decoder pcm_s24be_encoder
pcm_s24daud_decoder pcm_s24daud_encoder
pcm_s24le_decoder pcm_s24le_encoder
pcm_s32be_decoder pcm_s32be_encoder
pcm_s32le_decoder pcm_s32le_encoder
pcm_u8_decoder pcm_u8_encoder
pcm_u16be_decoder pcm_u16be_encoder
pcm_u16le_decoder pcm_u16le_encoder
pcm_u24be_decoder pcm_u24be_encoder
pcm_u24le_decoder pcm_u24le_encoder
pcm_u32be_decoder pcm_u32be_encoder
pcm_u32le_decoder pcm_u32le_encoder'
pcm_u16be_decoder='yes'
pcm_u16be_demuxer='yes'
pcm_u16be_encoder='yes'
pcm_u16be_muxer='yes'
pcm_u16le_decoder='yes'
pcm_u16le_demuxer='yes'
pcm_u16le_encoder='yes'
pcm_u16le_muxer='yes'
pcm_u24be_decoder='yes'
pcm_u24be_demuxer='yes'
pcm_u24be_encoder='yes'
pcm_u24be_muxer='yes'
pcm_u24le_decoder='yes'
pcm_u24le_demuxer='yes'
pcm_u24le_encoder='yes'
pcm_u24le_muxer='yes'
pcm_u32be_decoder='yes'
pcm_u32be_demuxer='yes'
pcm_u32be_encoder='yes'
pcm_u32be_muxer='yes'
pcm_u32le_decoder='yes'
pcm_u32le_demuxer='yes'
pcm_u32le_encoder='yes'
pcm_u32le_muxer='yes'
pcm_u8_decoder='yes'
pcm_u8_demuxer='yes'
pcm_u8_encoder='yes'
pcm_u8_muxer='yes'
pcm_u8_test='yes'
pcm_zork_decoder='yes'
pcx_decoder='yes'
pcx_encoder='yes'
pcx_test='yes'
pcx_test_deps=' pcx_encoder pcx_decoder'
pgm_decoder='yes'
pgm_encoder='yes'
pgm_test='yes'
pgm_test_deps=' pgm_encoder pgm_decoder'
pgmpipe_test='yes'
pgmpipe_test_deps=' pgm_encoder pgm_decoder'
pgmyuv_decoder='yes'
pgmyuv_encoder='yes'
pgssub_decoder='yes'
pic='yes'
pictor_decoder='yes'
pipe_protocol='yes'
pixdesc_test='yes'
pixdesctest_filter='yes'
pixfmt_test='yes'
pixfmt_test_deps=' rawvideo_muxer rawvideo_demuxer'
pixfmts_copy_test='yes'
pixfmts_crop_test='yes'
pixfmts_hflip_test='yes'
pixfmts_null_test='yes'
pixfmts_pad_test='yes'
pixfmts_scale_test='yes'
pixfmts_vflip_test='yes'
pkg_config_default='pkg-config'
pmp_demuxer='yes'
png_decoder='yes'
png_decoder_select='zlib'
png_encoder='yes'
png_encoder_select='zlib'
png_parser='yes'
png_test='yes'
png_test_deps=' png_encoder png_decoder'
pnm_parser='yes'
postproc='yes'
postproc_deps='gpl'
postproc_version_default='current'
pp2_test='yes'
pp2_test_deps='mp_filter'
pp3_test='yes'
pp3_test_deps='mp_filter'
pp4_test='yes'
pp4_test_deps='mp_filter'
pp5_test='yes'
pp5_test_deps='mp_filter'
pp6_test='yes'
pp6_test_deps='mp_filter'
pp_test='yes'
pp_test_deps='mp_filter'
ppc4xx='yes'
ppc4xx_deps='ppc'
ppm_decoder='yes'
ppm_encoder='yes'
ppm_test='yes'
ppm_test_deps=' ppm_encoder ppm_decoder'
ppmpipe_test='yes'
ppmpipe_test_deps=' ppm_encoder ppm_decoder'
prefix='/data/data/info.guardianproject.ffmpeg/app_opt'
prefix_default='/usr/local'
prores_anatoliy_encoder='yes'
prores_decoder='yes'
prores_encoder='yes'
prores_kostya_encoder='yes'
prores_kostya_test='yes'
prores_lgpl_decoder='yes'
prores_test='yes'
protocols_if_any='applehttp_protocol
bluray_protocol
cache_protocol
concat_protocol
crypto_protocol
file_protocol
gopher_protocol
hls_protocol
http_protocol
httpproxy_protocol
https_protocol
mmsh_protocol
mmst_protocol
md5_protocol
pipe_protocol
rtmp_protocol
rtp_protocol
sctp_protocol
tcp_protocol
tls_protocol
udp_protocol
librtmp_protocol
librtmpe_protocol
librtmps_protocol
librtmpt_protocol
librtmpte_protocol'
psp_muxer='yes'
psp_muxer_select='mov_muxer'
ptx_decoder='yes'
pulse_indev_deps='libpulse'
pva_demuxer='yes'
qcelp_decoder='yes'
qcelp_decoder_select='lsp'
qcp_demuxer='yes'
qdm2_decoder='yes'
qdm2_decoder_select='mdct rdft mpegaudiodsp'
qdraw_decoder='yes'
qpeg_decoder='yes'
qtrle_decoder='yes'
qtrle_encoder='yes'
qtrle_test='yes'
qtrlegray_test='yes'
quotes='""'
r='md5'
r10k_decoder='yes'
r10k_encoder='yes'
r210_decoder='yes'
r210_encoder='yes'
r210_test='yes'
r3d_demuxer='yes'
ra144_test='yes'
ra_144_decoder='yes'
ra_144_encoder='yes'
ra_144_encoder_select='lpc'
ra_288_decoder='yes'
ralf_decoder='yes'
ralf_decoder_select='golomb'
ranlib='ranlib'
rawvideo_decoder='yes'
rawvideo_demuxer='yes'
rawvideo_encoder='yes'
rawvideo_muxer='yes'
rc_test='yes'
rc_test_deps=' mpeg4_encoder mpeg4_decoder'
rdft_select='fft'
redact_filter='yes'
remove_extradata_bsf='yes'
removelogo_filter='yes'
removelogo_filter_deps='avcodec avformat swscale'
resample_filter='yes'
resample_filter_deps='avresample'
rgb_test='yes'
rgb_test_deps=' rawvideo_encoder rawvideo_decoder'
rgbtestsrc_filter='yes'
rl2_decoder='yes'
rl2_demuxer='yes'
rm_demuxer='yes'
rm_muxer='yes'
rm_test='yes'
rm_test_deps=' rm_muxer rm_demuxer'
roq_decoder='yes'
roq_demuxer='yes'
roq_dpcm_decoder='yes'
roq_dpcm_encoder='yes'
roq_encoder='yes'
roq_muxer='yes'
roq_test='yes'
roq_test_deps=' roq_encoder roq_decoder'
roqaudio_test='yes'
rpl_demuxer='yes'
rpza_decoder='yes'
rso_demuxer='yes'
rso_muxer='yes'
rso_test='yes'
rtmp_protocol='yes'
rtmp_protocol_deps='!librtmp_protocol'
rtmp_protocol_select='tcp_protocol'
rtp_demuxer='yes'
rtp_demuxer_select='sdp_demuxer'
rtp_muxer='yes'
rtp_protocol='yes'
rtp_protocol_select='udp_protocol'
rtpdec_select='asf_demuxer rm_demuxer rtp_protocol mpegts_demuxer mov_demuxer'
rtsp_demuxer='yes'
rtsp_demuxer_select='http_protocol rtpdec'
rtsp_muxer='yes'
rtsp_muxer_select='rtp_muxer http_protocol rtp_protocol'
runtime_cpudetect='yes'
rv10_decoder='yes'
rv10_decoder_select='h263_decoder'
rv10_encoder='yes'
rv10_encoder_select='h263_encoder'
rv10_test='yes'
rv10_test_deps=' rv10_encoder rv10_decoder'
rv20_decoder='yes'
rv20_decoder_select='h263_decoder'
rv20_encoder='yes'
rv20_encoder_select='h263_encoder'
rv20_test='yes'
rv20_test_deps=' rv20_encoder rv20_decoder'
rv30_decoder='yes'
rv30_decoder_select='golomb h264chroma h264pred h264qpel'
rv30_parser='yes'
rv40_decoder='yes'
rv40_decoder_select='golomb h264chroma h264pred h264qpel'
rv40_parser='yes'
s302m_decoder='yes'
safe_bitstream_reader='yes'
sap_demuxer='yes'
sap_demuxer_select='sdp_demuxer'
sap_muxer='yes'
sap_muxer_select='rtp_muxer rtp_protocol'
sbg_demuxer='yes'
scale200_test='yes'
scale500_test='yes'
scale_filter_deps='swscale'
sctp_protocol='yes'
sctp_protocol_deps='network netinet_sctp_h'
sdl_outdev_deps='sdl'
sdp_demuxer='yes'
sdp_demuxer_select='rtpdec'
seek_ac3_ac3_test='yes'
seek_adpcm_ima_wav_test='yes'
seek_adpcm_ms_wav_test='yes'
seek_adpcm_qt_aiff_test='yes'
seek_adpcm_swf_flv_test='yes'
seek_adpcm_yam_wav_test='yes'
seek_alac_m4a_test='yes'
seek_asv1_avi_test='yes'
seek_asv2_avi_test='yes'
seek_dnxhd_1080i_mov_test='yes'
seek_dnxhd_720p_dnxhd_test='yes'
seek_dnxhd_720p_rd_dnxhd_test='yes'
seek_dv411_dv_test='yes'
seek_dv50_dv_test='yes'
seek_dv_dv_test='yes'
seek_error_mpeg4_adv_avi_test='yes'
seek_ffv1_avi_test='yes'
seek_flac_flac_test='yes'
seek_flashsv_flv_test='yes'
seek_flv_flv_test='yes'
seek_h261_avi_test='yes'
seek_h263_avi_test='yes'
seek_h263p_avi_test='yes'
seek_huffyuv_avi_test='yes'
seek_image_bmp_test='yes'
seek_image_jpg_test='yes'
seek_image_pcx_test='yes'
seek_image_pgm_test='yes'
seek_image_ppm_test='yes'
seek_image_sgi_test='yes'
seek_image_tga_test='yes'
seek_image_tiff_test='yes'
seek_jpegls_avi_test='yes'
seek_lavf_aif_test='yes'
seek_lavf_al_test='yes'
seek_lavf_asf_test='yes'
seek_lavf_au_test='yes'
seek_lavf_avi_test='yes'
seek_lavf_dv_test='yes'
seek_lavf_ffm_test='yes'
seek_lavf_flv_test='yes'
seek_lavf_gif_test='yes'
seek_lavf_gxf_test='yes'
seek_lavf_mkv_test='yes'
seek_lavf_mmf_test='yes'
seek_lavf_mov_test='yes'
seek_lavf_mpg_test='yes'
seek_lavf_mxf_d10_test='yes'
seek_lavf_mxf_d10_test_deps='mxf_d10_test'
seek_lavf_mxf_test='yes'
seek_lavf_nut_test='yes'
seek_lavf_ogg_test='yes'
seek_lavf_rm_test='yes'
seek_lavf_swf_test='yes'
seek_lavf_ts_test='yes'
seek_lavf_ul_test='yes'
seek_lavf_voc_test='yes'
seek_lavf_wav_test='yes'
seek_lavf_wtv_test='yes'
seek_lavf_y4m_test='yes'
seek_ljpeg_avi_test='yes'
seek_mjpeg_avi_test='yes'
seek_mp2_mp2_test='yes'
seek_mpeg1_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg1b_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg2_422_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg2_idct_int_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg2i_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg2ivlc_qprd_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg2thread_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg2threadivlc_mpg_test='yes'
seek_mpeg4_adap_avi_test='yes'
seek_mpeg4_adv_avi_test='yes'
seek_mpeg4_nr_avi_test='yes'
seek_mpeg4_qprd_avi_test='yes'
seek_mpeg4_rc_avi_test='yes'
seek_mpeg4_thread_avi_test='yes'
seek_msmpeg4_avi_test='yes'
seek_msmpeg4v2_avi_test='yes'
seek_odivx_mp4_test='yes'
seek_pbmpipe_pbm_test='yes'
seek_pcm_alaw_wav_test='yes'
seek_pcm_f32be_au_test='yes'
seek_pcm_f32le_wav_test='yes'
seek_pcm_f64be_au_test='yes'
seek_pcm_f64le_wav_test='yes'
seek_pcm_mulaw_wav_test='yes'
seek_pcm_s16be_mov_test='yes'
seek_pcm_s16le_wav_test='yes'
seek_pcm_s24be_mov_test='yes'
seek_pcm_s24le_wav_test='yes'
seek_pcm_s32be_mov_test='yes'
seek_pcm_s32le_wav_test='yes'
seek_pcm_s8_mov_test='yes'
seek_pcm_u8_wav_test='yes'
seek_pgmpipe_pgm_test='yes'
seek_ppmpipe_ppm_test='yes'
seek_rgb_avi_test='yes'
seek_roqav_roq_test='yes'
seek_rv10_rm_test='yes'
seek_rv20_rm_test='yes'
seek_snow53_avi_test='yes'
seek_snow_avi_test='yes'
seek_svq1_mov_test='yes'
seek_wmv1_avi_test='yes'
seek_wmv2_avi_test='yes'
seek_yuv_avi_test='yes'
segafilm_demuxer='yes'
segment_muxer='yes'
select_filter='yes'
select_test='yes'
setdar_filter='yes'
setdar_test='yes'
setfield_filter='yes'
setpts_filter='yes'
setsar_filter='yes'
setsar_test='yes'
settb_filter='yes'
sgi_decoder='yes'
sgi_encoder='yes'
sgi_test='yes'
sgi_test_deps=' sgi_encoder sgi_decoder'
shared='no'
shlibdir_default='${prefix}/lib'
shorten_decoder='yes'
shorten_decoder_select='golomb'
shorten_demuxer='yes'
showinfo_filter='yes'
siff_demuxer='yes'
silencedetect_filter='yes'
sipr_decoder='yes'
sipr_decoder_select='lsp'
slicify_filter='yes'
smackaud_decoder='yes'
smacker_decoder='yes'
smacker_demuxer='yes'
smc_decoder='yes'
smjpeg_demuxer='yes'
smjpeg_muxer='yes'
sndio_indev_deps='sndio_h'
sndio_outdev_deps='sndio_h'
snow_decoder='yes'
snow_decoder_select='dwt'
snow_encoder='yes'
snow_encoder_select='aandct dwt'
snow_test='yes'
snow_test_deps=' snow_encoder snow_decoder'
snowll_test='yes'
snowll_test_deps=' snow_encoder snow_decoder'
sol_demuxer='yes'
sol_dpcm_decoder='yes'
sonic_decoder='yes'
sonic_decoder_select='golomb'
sonic_encoder='yes'
sonic_encoder_select='golomb'
sonic_ls_encoder='yes'
sonic_ls_encoder_select='golomb'
source_path='.'
sox_demuxer='yes'
sox_muxer='yes'
sox_test='yes'
sp5x_decoder='yes'
spdif_demuxer='yes'
spdif_muxer='yes'
spdif_muxer_select='aac_parser'
split_filter='yes'
srt_decoder='yes'
srt_demuxer='yes'
srt_encoder='yes'
srt_muxer='yes'
sse='yes'
sse_deps='mmx'
ssse3='yes'
ssse3_deps='sse'
static='yes'
str_demuxer='yes'
strip_default='strip'
stripping='yes'
suf1='_muxer'
suf2='_demuxer'
sunrast_decoder='yes'
sunrast_encoder='yes'
sunrast_test='yes'
super2xsai_filter='yes'
super2xsai_filter_deps='gpl'
svq1_decoder='yes'
svq1_encoder='yes'
svq1_encoder_select='aandct'
svq1_test='yes'
svq1_test_deps=' svq1_encoder svq1_decoder'
svq3_decoder='yes'
svq3_decoder_select='golomb h264chroma h264dsp h264pred h264qpel'
svq3_decoder_suggest='zlib'
swapuv_filter='yes'
swf_demuxer='yes'
swf_muxer='yes'
swf_test='yes'
swf_test_deps=' swf_muxer swf_demuxer'
swresample='yes'
swscale='yes'
swscale_alpha='yes'
symver_if_any='symver_asm_label symver_gnu_asm'
sysroot='../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-3/arch-arm'
targa_decoder='yes'
targa_encoder='yes'
target_os='linux'
target_os_default='linux'
target_path='$(CURDIR)'
tcp_protocol='yes'
tcp_protocol_deps='network'
tests='yuv4mpeg'
testsrc_filter='yes'
testsrc_test='yes'
text2movsub_bsf='yes'
tg2_muxer='yes'
tg2_muxer_select='mov_muxer'
tga_test='yes'
tga_test_deps=' targa_encoder targa_decoder'
tgp_muxer='yes'
tgp_muxer_select='mov_muxer'
theora_decoder='yes'
theora_decoder_select='vp3_decoder'
thing='muxer'
thp_decoder='yes'
thp_demuxer='yes'
thumbnail_filter='yes'
thumbnail_test='yes'
tiertexseq_demuxer='yes'
tiertexseqvideo_decoder='yes'
tiff_decoder='yes'
tiff_decoder_suggest='zlib'
tiff_encoder='yes'
tiff_encoder_suggest='zlib'
tiff_test='yes'
tiff_test_deps=' tiff_encoder tiff_decoder'
tile_filter='yes'
tinterlace_filter='yes'
tinterlace_filter_deps='gpl'
tls_protocol='yes'
tls_protocol_deps_any='openssl gnutls'
tls_protocol_select='tcp_protocol'
tmv_decoder='yes'
tmv_demuxer='yes'
transpose_filter='yes'
transpose_test='yes'
truehd_decoder='yes'
truehd_decoder_select='mlp_decoder'
truehd_demuxer='yes'
truehd_muxer='yes'
truemotion1_decoder='yes'
truemotion2_decoder='yes'
truespeech_decoder='yes'
ts_test='yes'
ts_test_deps=' mpegts_muxer mpegts_demuxer'
tscc_decoder='yes'
tscc_decoder_select='zlib'
tta_decoder='yes'
tta_demuxer='yes'
tty_demuxer='yes'
twinvq_decoder='yes'
twinvq_decoder_select='mdct lsp sinewin'
txd_decoder='yes'
txd_demuxer='yes'
udp_protocol='yes'
udp_protocol_deps='network'
ulti_decoder='yes'
unsharp_filter='yes'
unsharp_test='yes'
utvideo_decoder='yes'
v='PROTOCOL_LIST'
v210_decoder='yes'
v210_encoder='yes'
v210_test='yes'
v210x_decoder='yes'
v308_decoder='yes'
v308_encoder='yes'
v308_test='yes'
v408_decoder='yes'
v408_encoder='yes'
v408_test='yes'
v410_decoder='yes'
v410_encoder='yes'
v4l2_indev_deps_any='linux_videodev2_h sys_videoio_h'
v4l_indev_deps='linux_videodev_h'
vaapi_deps='va_va_h'
value='yes'
var='md5_muxer'
vb_decoder='yes'
vble_decoder='yes'
vc1_crystalhd_decoder='yes'
vc1_crystalhd_decoder_select='crystalhd'
vc1_decoder='yes'
vc1_decoder_select='h263_decoder h264chroma h264qpel'
vc1_demuxer='yes'
vc1_dxva2_hwaccel='yes'
vc1_dxva2_hwaccel_deps='dxva2api_h'
vc1_dxva2_hwaccel_select='dxva2 vc1_decoder'
vc1_parser='yes'
vc1_vaapi_hwaccel='yes'
vc1_vaapi_hwaccel_select='vaapi vc1_decoder'
vc1_vdpau_decoder='yes'
vc1_vdpau_decoder_select='vdpau vc1_decoder'
vc1image_decoder='yes'
vc1image_decoder_select='vc1_decoder'
vc1t_demuxer='yes'
vc1t_muxer='yes'
vcr1_decoder='yes'
vda_deps='VideoDecodeAcceleration_VDADecoder_h pthreads'
vdpau_deps='vdpau_vdpau_h vdpau_vdpau_x11_h'
version3='yes'
vflip_crop_test='yes'
vflip_filter='yes'
vflip_test='yes'
vflip_vflip_test='yes'
vfpv3='yes'
vfpv3_deps='armvfp'
vfwcap_indev_deps='capCreateCaptureWindow vfwcap_defines'
vfwcap_indev_extralibs='-lavicap32'
vis='yes'
vis_deps='sparc'
vmd_demuxer='yes'
vmdaudio_decoder='yes'
vmdvideo_decoder='yes'
vmnc_decoder='yes'
voc_demuxer='yes'
voc_muxer='yes'
voc_s16_test='yes'
voc_test='yes'
voc_test_deps=' voc_muxer voc_demuxer'
volume_filter='yes'
vorbis_decoder='yes'
vorbis_decoder_select='mdct'
vorbis_encoder='yes'
vorbis_encoder_select='mdct'
vorbis_parser='yes'
vp3_decoder='yes'
vp3_parser='yes'
vp5_decoder='yes'
vp6_decoder='yes'
vp6_decoder_select='huffman'
vp6a_decoder='yes'
vp6a_decoder_select='vp6_decoder'
vp6f_decoder='yes'
vp6f_decoder_select='vp6_decoder'
vp8_decoder='yes'
vp8_decoder_select='h264pred h264qpel'
vp8_parser='yes'
vqa_decoder='yes'
vqf_demuxer='yes'
vref_test='yes'
w64_demuxer='yes'
w64_demuxer_deps='wav_demuxer'
wav_demuxer='yes'
wav_muxer='yes'
wav_test='yes'
wav_test_deps=' wav_muxer wav_demuxer'
wavpack_decoder='yes'
wc3_demuxer='yes'
webm_muxer='yes'
wmalossless_decoder='yes'
wmapro_decoder='yes'
wmapro_decoder_select='mdct sinewin'
wmav1_decoder='yes'
wmav1_decoder_select='mdct sinewin'
wmav1_encoder='yes'
wmav1_encoder_select='mdct sinewin'
wmav1_test_deps=' wmav1_encoder wmav1_decoder'
wmav2_decoder='yes'
wmav2_decoder_select='mdct sinewin'
wmav2_encoder='yes'
wmav2_encoder_select='mdct sinewin'
wmav2_test_deps=' wmav2_encoder wmav2_decoder'
wmavoice_decoder='yes'
wmavoice_decoder_select='lsp rdft dct mdct sinewin'
wmv1_decoder='yes'
wmv1_decoder_select='h263_decoder'
wmv1_encoder='yes'
wmv1_encoder_select='h263_encoder'
wmv1_test='yes'
wmv1_test_deps=' wmv1_encoder wmv1_decoder'
wmv2_decoder='yes'
wmv2_decoder_select='h263_decoder'
wmv2_encoder='yes'
wmv2_encoder_select='h263_encoder'
wmv2_test='yes'
wmv2_test_deps=' wmv2_encoder wmv2_decoder'
wmv3_crystalhd_decoder='yes'
wmv3_crystalhd_decoder_select='crystalhd'
wmv3_decoder='yes'
wmv3_decoder_select='vc1_decoder'
wmv3_dxva2_hwaccel='yes'
wmv3_dxva2_hwaccel_select='vc1_dxva2_hwaccel'
wmv3_vaapi_hwaccel='yes'
wmv3_vaapi_hwaccel_select='vc1_vaapi_hwaccel'
wmv3_vdpau_decoder='yes'
wmv3_vdpau_decoder_select='vc1_vdpau_decoder'
wmv3image_decoder='yes'
wmv3image_decoder_select='wmv3_decoder'
wnv1_decoder='yes'
ws_snd1_decoder='yes'
wsaud_demuxer='yes'
wsvqa_demuxer='yes'
wtv_demuxer='yes'
wtv_muxer='yes'
wtv_test='yes'
wv_demuxer='yes'
x11_grab_device_indev_deps='x11grab XShmCreateImage'
x86_64_suggest='cmov fast_cmov'
xa_demuxer='yes'
xan_dpcm_decoder='yes'
xan_wc3_decoder='yes'
xan_wc4_decoder='yes'
xbin_decoder='yes'
xbin_demuxer='yes'
xbm_decoder='yes'
xbm_encoder='yes'
xbm_test='yes'
xl_decoder='yes'
xmv_demuxer='yes'
xsub_decoder='yes'
xsub_encoder='yes'
xwd_decoder='yes'
xwd_encoder='yes'
xwd_test='yes'
xwma_demuxer='yes'
y41p_decoder='yes'
y41p_encoder='yes'
y41p_test='yes'
yadif_filter='yes'
yadif_filter_deps='gpl'
yasm='yes'
yasmexe_default='yasm'
yop_decoder='yes'
yop_demuxer='yes'
yuv4_decoder='yes'
yuv4_encoder='yes'
yuv4_test='yes'
yuv4mpeg_test='yes'
yuv4mpeg_test_deps=' yuv4mpegpipe_muxer yuv4mpegpipe_demuxer'
yuv4mpegpipe_demuxer='yes'
yuv4mpegpipe_muxer='yes'
yuv_test='yes'
yuv_test_deps=' rawvideo_encoder rawvideo_decoder'
zerocodec_decoder='yes'
zerocodec_decoder_select='zlib'
zlib='yes'
zlib_decoder='yes'
zlib_decoder_select='zlib'
zlib_encoder='yes'
zlib_encoder_select='zlib'
zlib_test='yes'
zlib_test_deps='zlib'
zmbv_decoder='yes'
zmbv_decoder_select='zlib'
zmbv_encoder='yes'
zmbv_encoder_select='zlib'
zmbv_test='yes'
zmbv_test_deps='zlib'
mktemp -u XXXXXX
tdvcmv
WARNING: Unknown C compiler ../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc, unable to select optimal CFLAGS
check_ld cc
check_cc
BEGIN /tmp/ffconf.cccnIK8E.c
    1   int main(void){ return 0; }
END /tmp/ffconf.cccnIK8E.c
../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I../x264 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -mcpu=cortex-a8 -c -o /tmp/ffconf.G33Y3DLz.o /tmp/ffconf.cccnIK8E.c
./configure: 640: ./configure: ../Downloads/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: not found
C compiler test failed.
```

In below I found that there is mistake in installation
[Error " C compiler works... no" when run build_android.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925046/error-c-compiler-works-no-when-run-build-android-sh)

Try getting rid of everything but "-DANDROID -mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a" in your extra cflags, and remove the crazy extra quotation marks and see if it compiles.

I don't understand what to remove from which file, please can anybody suggest me how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

a sample config on 12.04 (x64) with ndk r8 or r9 if it helps??

configuration: --enable-cross-compile --arch=armv7-a --cpu=cortex-a9 --target-os=linux --enable-runtime-cpudetect --prefix=/output --enable-pic --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-small --cross-prefix=/usr/local/src/android-ndk-r8b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --sysroot=/usr/local/src/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-14/arch-arm --enable-version3 --enable-gpl --enable-memalign-hack --disable-doc --enable-yasm --enable-decoder=mjpeg --enable-decoder=rawvideo --enable-encoder=libx264 --enable-muxer=mp4 --enable-demuxer=image2 --enable-demuxer=mjpeg --enable-demuxer=mp4 --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-parser=mjpeg --enable-filter=buffer --enable-filter=buffersink --enable-filter=drawbox --enable-filter=overlay --enable-filter=redact --enable-protocol=file --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --disable-ffserver --disable-network --enable-libx264 --enable-zlib --extra-cflags='-mfloat-abi=softfp -marm -march=armv7-a -mtu  libavutil

i think that your error in the config can be addressed with careful attention to a toolchain and corresponding config flags.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iP1vieZy  also see that one for an old "guardian X264 " module config on 12.04 (x64)